# $addToSet in a nested Array item

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Considering the following

User collection & sample User document

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("575c01f7b8e5999addeb598c"), 
"username" : "test.1@gmail.com", 
"password" : "<password>", 
"firstName" : "Test, 
"lastName" : "User"
}
```

I am trying to run an update request to add an entry in userData.eventData which is meant to be an array

In mongo script I can do

```
> db.Users.update({_id: ObjectId("575c01f7b8e5999addeb598c")}, {"$addToSet":{"userData.eventData":"My event"}} )
```

And I have the following result : userData is created as an Object and eventData as a nested Array

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.Users.find({_id: ObjectId("575c01f7b8e5999addeb598c")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("575c01f7b8e5999addeb598c"), "username" : "test.1@gmail.com", "password" : "<password>", "firstName" : "Test", "lastName" : "User", "userData" : { "eventData" : [ "My event" ] } }
```

While running the same logic in mongo (using driver version 2.1.21)

```
// with a properly initialized db object
db.collection("Users").update({"_id" : ObjectId("575c01f7b8e5999addeb598c")}, {"$addToSet": { "userData.eventData": "My Event"}}, function(err, result) {
    // do something
});
```

I receive the following response

```
result:Object
    n:0
    nModified:0
    ok:1
```

And indeed the database entry is unchanged.

Is that the way it is meant to behave? I can easily fix this by creating the userData.eventData array but I found disturbing the fact that node's Mongo driver and mongo shell didn't behave the same on this

Thanks in advance for your help & advice

**Edit 13/6/16**
Mistake was on my side, I missed a 'new' before 'ObjectId(...' in node. With it, it behaves exactly the same as in mongo shell (i.e. 'userData' is created as an Object and it includes 'eventData' array)

No issue, then :)

Comment: The `n:0` means your update didn't find a matching document, so you may be querying the wrong database or something like that.

Comment: Indeed, the trick was to add a 'new' before ObjectId in the node code. Thanks a lot @JohnnyHK (I edited my original post for archive)

Answer (score 0):

[Update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), updates an already existing object in your document. 
What you want is [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) or use upset which creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria

```
db.collection.update(
   { name: "Andy" },
   {
      name: "Andy",
      rating: 1,
      score: 1
   },
   { upsert: true }
);
```

If you wanted to add an object to your array, you would need $push

```
// Insert a document in the capped collection
 function push (db, collection, search, data, callback) {
    db.collection(collection).update(
        search, {
            $push: data
        }, function (err, result) {
            console.log("New object pushed");
            callback(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @John for your reply. Actually I wanted to update an existing document by adding a data into an array nested into a de-facto subdocument. My User object would be structured as {username: "Andy", "userData": {"eventData": ["my event"]}}. I used $addToSet but could have used $push indeed (I believe in this case they behave the same). My issue was to possibly create the "userData" and "eventData" structures which could be null initially. My bug was due to a missing "new" before ObjectID() in node